# How to return byte[] from web api and reading it on client

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a WebAPI that returns a byte[].
However, when i try to read the byte[] i get a different result than what i have sent. i am not sure why this happens. I see that the `response.ContentLength` is significantly bigger than the byte[] length i'm sending. 
EDIT: Also the content type of the response is json.

The WebAPI:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetReport(JObject reportParametersJson)
    {
        try
        {
            var reportParameters = reportParametersJson.ToObject<ReportParameters>();
            var results = GetReportFromWorker(reportParameters);

            return Ok(results[0]); // results[0] is the byte array
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

The client:

```
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:56165/api/reports");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            var requestParameter = new ReportParameters
            {
                ReportType = ReportType1,
                Parameters = new string[] {"2017-02-07", "2019-02-10"}
            };
            string json = serializer.Serialize(requestParameter);
            sw.Write(json);
            sw.Flush();
        }

        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string ct = response.ContentType;
        Stream objStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(objStream);
        byte[] buffer = breader.ReadBytes((int)response.ContentLength);
        var path = @"C:\ITextSharpExports\filename.pdf";
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, buffer);
        return;
```

Comment: Base64 the bytes on the server then send as json and decode on the client

Comment: Did you actually look at the content returned by the method, or its contentType?

Comment: ASP.net Core? Full fat?

Comment: @spender added edit: content type of the response is json (why?)

Comment: @spender not core, its 4.5.1

Comment: WebAPI Controller.Ok() serializes by default to JSON. I've marked a dupe that should see you good.

Comment: @spender that did the trick. thank you!